# What are good ways to lose weight for people being mentally active?

Tags: nutrition, diet, weight-loss, body-weight

I was trying to find some good ways to lose weight. Especially for people above 100kg (~180cm height) who are mentally active at work, since they need a lot of sugar/glucose or something similar for their brains in order to focus.

Are there any good diets for people being mentally active which won't affect the everyday brain activities?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add sugar to your diet to function. Schedule a checkup with a doctor.

Comment: This question interest me, too. It refers to people who do a lot of mental activity, but have little time for exercise. So, closing it is counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have been given a clean bill of health from your doctor (e.g. metabolic problems such as diabetes, thyroid problems etc. have been ruled out), except that you are overweight. The medical advice given to you is that you should lose weight via dieting and exercise. The problem now is that if you attempt to do that, you feel tired, have a lack of energy that is interfering with your ability to concentrate at work.

The best thing you can do is to visit your doctor again, but this time [stick to this advice](http://www.webmd.com/men/features/tips-for-a-successful-doctor-visit), which in this case means that you should write up what you are eating, how much exercise you get, what your sleep habits are, and what your energy levels are day by day. Make clear that things are not going well and that this is a persistent problem as demonstrated by your records. The doctor can then assess whether new tests are necessary, because a clean bill of health may only refer to having ruled out the most common metabolic disorders, there may well be other not so common medical problems that have not yet been ruled out. The more detailed information you can provide your doctor, the better that assessment can be made.

If the doctor still thinks there is nothing wrong, he/she could refer you to a dietitian.

Comment: Why would exercise make him feel "lack of energy" can you elaborate of this false information ?

Comment: @Hakim Overweight people will often already get that feeling when reducing calorie intake before doing any exercise. They feel hungry and if they ignore that feeling then hunger becomes tiredness. This is why they find it so difficult to eat less and get more exercise. This will of course be different for different people, but then the people for whom this effect is less of a problem will find it easier to lose weight, so from the group of people who try to lose weight you are going to end up with people who struggle because of this reason.

Comment: @CountIblis - Even though the question is locked, existing answer still need to conform to site standards. Please add appropriate links supporting your assertions, or your answer may be deleted.

Comment: @JohnP I included a link to how to communicate effectively with a doctor, as that's what the question fundamentally is about, or at least the way we can address this here (no medical advice but instead pointing out that one should seek medical advice).